# How to pass TC String to Admob with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob, one-trust

I implemented a consent management platform called [OneTrust SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/onetrust_publishers_native_cmp). This works and I can see users' consent choices on various cookies. Currently, the app getting no ads from AdMob at all, and my goal is to debug it by checking the TC String.

OneTrust package is compiled and I can't debug it but I've read that CMPs are usually writing this string to local storage and ads SDK automatically obtain it.

> IMA SDK and Mobile Ads SDK will automatically obtain, parse, and
> respect the TC string from within local storage.

https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9805023?hl=en

I wonder if anyone worked with GDPR with flutter knows about how to get or pass this TC String to Google Ads.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm testing the Usercentrics App SDK right now - again, no results from the TC string. The UMP from Google doesn't really work either (yet?) ...